# Why do we give so much importance to energy, i.e., the conserved quantity under time symmetry?

Tags: energy, particle-physics, cosmology, energy-conservation

In almost all equations—from [GR](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/General_relativity) to [QFT](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quantum_field_theory)—energy conservation is a tool for solving those equations, but we know that energy on large scales is not conserved.

Why do we still use this (not) conserved quantity in our fundamental laws of physics?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As a complement to Nickolas's great answer, note that throughout physics, *conservation laws* are so useful that even *approximate* conservation laws can be of enormous interest. Conservation laws let you deduce aspects of the behavior of a physical system, without needing to actually solve equations. This is tremendously useful for (a) building intuition, (b) quickly solving problems, (c) providing ways to check if there are mistakes in the solutions to the equations.

Some examples of approximate conservation laws include:

- Mass (which is conserved to a very good approximation in non-relativistic physics, but is not conserved in special relativity)
- Kinetic energy is approximately conserved in collisions which are approximately-but-not-exactly elastic. "Elastic" collisions in a freshman college physics lab will often be analyzed as if kinetic energy were exactly conserved.
- Baryon number (this is used in particle physics)

Energy is not an exact conservation law in general in GR (although in some cases it is). However, even in GR, energy is *approximately conserved* locally -- meaning, on time scales short compared to the scale on which the gravitational field is changing in time. In fact, in ordinary circumstances in a lab, this conservation law holds to *extremely* high precision. That's why energy conservation is still *useful*, even though it isn't *exact*.

Comment: AFAIK Lepton Numbers hold for all types of interactions (Strong, Weak, EM).

Comment: @asdasd Yes, you are right. I'll remove that.

Comment: 4-Momentum is conserved, assuming that Energy is conserved.
What this question is all about.

Comment: @asdasd Energy is not conserved in GR, in general.

Comment: Is the non conservation of Energy the discrepancy between GR and QM (I don't know anything about QFT to be honest)?

Comment: @asdasd I assume you are referring to the inability of standard quantization methods to produce a sensible quantum theory of gravity. In that case, no, these are unrelated issues. You can read more about energy in GR here: https://math.ucr.edu/home/baez/physics/Relativity/GR/energy_gr.html, and you can read more about quantizing GR here: https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/quantum-gravity/#2

Answer (score 10):

At the end of the day, physics is an experimental science. If your experiment can't measure some effects, you might just as well ignore them. That is quite often the case with cosmological effects.

If you want to be technically correct in all details, we should describe all phenomena in terms of, at least, the [Standard Model](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_Model) in curved spacetime (with corrections due to considering GR as a QFT). Of course, this is ridiculously difficult, and quite often unnecessary. When one is describing collisions at the [LHC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Large_Hadron_Collider), gravitational effects are hardly relevant, so one can just treat QFT in [Minkowski spacetime](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minkowski_space) and assume energy is conserved. While technically it isn't, for those phenomena it is approximately conserved up to a very good accuracy (better than what our detectors can distinguish at least). Similarly, cosmological effects will hardly be relevant for the motion of the Earth around the Sun, so we can also take energy to be approximately conserved to a very good accuracy.

It is similar to how you don't need to consider GR to compute the motion of a ball dropped off a building: you could use GR, but the corrections are so small that we might as well neglect them and work with a constant, Newtonian gravitational field. Of course, in fundamental physics things get a bit trickier, as ultimately you want to describe, well, the fundamental structure of the Universe. Nevertheless, we quite often aim at an aspect at a time. As you move towards "more fundamental" physics, these approximations will start to crumble down and you'll need to take these effects being neglected into account.

Comment: Even the newtonian gravitational field varies depending on radial distance from centre of the earth.

Comment: @sato I agree, what I meant is that even that can be neglected if you're dropping a ball off a building (assuming the building is small enough).

Comment: I totally understand why we approximate certain quantities/equations, but I'm especially asking about the "fundamental structure of the Universe".
Why would the presumption "Energy is conserved" (even tho False) lead us on the correct path?

Comment: @asdasd It is a matter of solving things one step at a time. If you want to write a completely fundamental theory, then you better take energy non-conservation into account. However, most Physics we do is effective: we are trying to push our knowledge further, without attempting at a Theory of Everything. It works because fundamental physics is often not "fully fundamental"

Comment: What we call fundamental physics usually means just that we're trying to go deeper than what we already know. Just a smaller set of "fundamental physicists" are actually trying to obtain a Theory of Everything or something that fundamental. Even in those cases, as far as I know it is common to first look for toy models before actually pursuing the actual Theory of Everything